# bootstrap 3 aligh all components to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

i like to alight all components to the left also like to control the sizing of the components
For example check the : div class="containerSelectBox checkbox_label "

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


  <style>
    /* Some custom styles to beautify this example */
    
    .demo-content {
      <!-- padding: 15px;
      -->font-size: 18px;
      min-height: 300px;
      background: #dbdfe5;
      <!-- margin-bottom: 10px;
      -->
    }
    
    .demo-content.bg-alt {
      background: #abb1b8;
    }
    
    .green {
      background: yellow;
      border: 1px solid lightgreen;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .containerSelectBox {
      overflow-y: scroll;
      <!-- width: 100%;
      -->height: 80px;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 1.42857143;
      color: #555;
      background-color: #fff;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
      -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
      -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
      transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }
    
    .checkbox_label label {
      margin: 0px 20px 0px 3px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 green ">
        <span class="text-left">
                <h3>
                    APP Configuration
                </h3>
            </span>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-left">Email</div>
            <div class="containerSelectBox checkbox_label col-xs-5 col-sm-5 pull-left" id="multi_select">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-left">Email:</div>
            <div class="containerSelectBox checkbox_label col-xs-5 col-sm-5 pull-left" id="multi_select2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-left">Email:</div>
            <div class="containerSelectBox checkbox_label col-xs-5 col-sm-5 pull-left" id="multi_select3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-left">Email:</div>
            <div class="containerSelectBox checkbox_label col-xs-5 col-sm-5 pull-left" id="multi_select4">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-left">IP:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 pull-left">
              <input type="text" required="required" id="foo3" class="form-control col-xs-5 col-sm-5" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 text-left">IP:</div>
            <div class=" col-xs-5 col-sm-5 pull-left">
              <input type="text" required="required" id="foo2" class="form-control col-xs-5 col-sm-5" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

which totally ignores the high CSS :
In the snippet, it looks wired and the main use of it will be in desktops.
currently, it looks like this :
[image]
I try to alight all to the left and respect the CSS high height: 80px;
as you can see there is gap between the text box and the text

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `<head>` it could do the trick

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

also, try updating to the Latest bootstrap.

Comment: i updated the question including your suggestion but it do not work

Comment: add this, and remove bootstrap 3 ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">```

Comment: i can't remove , this is the catch here i have to use bootstrap 3